# Where are UserChrome.css parameters like editBMPanel_locationRow documented?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, css

I want to use UserChrome.css to remove the 'Keyword' and 'Tags' fields from the 'Edit Bookmark' menu. I imagine that I need a parameter like `editBMPanel_locationRow`. Where are these documented?

Comment: Not sure why this question is closed. But for the bookmark panel in particular, its markup is defined at this location in Firefox's [source repository](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file): `./browser/components/places/content/editBookmarkPanel.inc.xhtml`. You can view the file online [here](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/browser/components/places/content/editBookmarkPanel.inc.xhtml). Those parameters are the IDs of various elements of the UI, and you can style them via `UserChrome.css` as you would normally for styling HTML elements by ID (`#someId { prop: val; }`).